# Android NDK file access (package name issue)

Tags: android, file-io, android-ndk

In an Android app, using NDK, I'm accessing a local file using `fopen`, `fclose`, etc. My app started out as HellloJNI (the supplied example). Accessing the file actually worked initially. The file path I used was `"/data/data/com.example.hellojni/files/Test.txt"`.

Naturally I don't want my app to be called HelloJNI forever, so I changed the package name (manifest/@package in AndroidManifest.xml) from `com.example.hellojni` to `com.example.mytest`. Accordingly, I use a different file path: `"/data/data/com.example.mytest/files/Test.txt"`. But the same call to `fopen("[...]", "w+")` that used to succeed now fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after manually creating the `files` folder below `/data/data/com.example.mytest`. In a way, it's obvious, but I still don't fully understand it, because I never created explicitly the `files` folder below `/data/data/com.example.hellojni`. So where did that one come from?

Edit:

Apparently calling `getFilesDir` creates the `Files` folder implicitly, so that mystery is solved :-)

Comment: where did you place the test.txt file? Did you push it to /data/data/com.example.mytest/files/ ?  I am asking this because I got an error after accessing it from /data/data/com.example.mytest/test.txt even after pushing test.txt to /data/data/com.example.mytest/.

Comment: As far as I remember (this was four years ago) I just created the folder. The files were written by the app, not pushed from ADB. So if you're pushing them, maybe the file owner is incorrect.